# Switch banners with load and interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, banner

I'm trying to make 2 banners changing on the same place, let me explain better:

Window load ok

loop{

1- Load Banner 1 (gif)

2- delay 6000 ms

3- Remove Banner 1

4- Load Banner 2 (gif)

5- delay 7500 ms

6- remove Banner 2

}

Im trying to do this, so all frames are loaded correctly, that's why I need the banner div to be loaded on the correct timing.

My code now (not working):

```
    $( window ).load(function() {
    function go() {
        $("#bannerkingbong").load("banner_king_bong.php");

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#bannerkingbong a').remove();
        }, 6000);

        $("#bannerultra").load("banner_ultra420.php");

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#bannerultra a').remove();
        }, 7500);
    }
    go();
});
```

If someone could help me.. I appreciate :) thanks.

Tested this, but no success:

```
$(function() {    
var queue = ["#bannerkingbong;http://smokebuddies.com.br/banner_king_bong.html", 3000, "empty;#bannerkingbong", "#bannerultra;http://smokebuddies.com.br/banner_ultra420.html", 4000, "empty;#bannerultra"];

(function next(queue) { 
    if(!queue.length) {
        return;
    }
    var action = queue.shift();

    //If wait action
    if($.isNumeric(action)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            next(queue);
        }, action);
        return;
    }


    var c = action.split(";");

    //If remove action
    if(c[0] === 'empty') {
        $(c[1]).empty();
        return next(queue);
    }

    //If load action
    $(c[0]).load(c[1], function() {
        return next(queue);
    });        
})(queue);
```

});

Comment: `load` is asynchronous. You need to use callback if you want some function to fire only after this function has completed.

Comment: *"not working"* is not a proper problem description that explains what is actually happening

Comment: sorry, i'm from brasil, i'm trying to do my best with my english :).

Answer (score 0):

My idea (or solution) is to create a queue of actions like this:

```
["#bannerkingbong;https://httpbin.org/user-agent", 
    3000, 
    "empty;#bannerkingbong", 
    "#bannerultra;https://httpbin.org/ip", 
    4000, 
    "empty;#bannerultra"]
```

**Action type 1** ( `#bannerkingbong;https://httpbin.org/user-agent`):

- load `https://httpbin.org/user-agent` into `#bannerkingbong`.

**Action type 2** ( `3000` ) integers:

- wait 3 seconds.

**Action type 3** `empty;#bannerultra`:

- empty the element with selector `#bannerultra`.

Now, you can play with the queue to chain your actions. Here is the code that will execute the queue:

```js
$(function() {    
    
    var queue = ["#bannerkingbong;https://httpbin.org/user-agent", 3000, "empty;#bannerkingbong", "#bannerultra;https://httpbin.org/ip", 4000, "empty;#bannerultra"];
    
    (function next(queue) { 
     if(!queue.length) {
         return;
        }
        var action = queue.shift();
        
        //If wait action
        if($.isNumeric(action)) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             next(queue);
            }, action);
            return;
        }
        
        
        var c = action.split(";");
        
        //If remove action
        if(c[0] === 'empty') {
         $(c[1]).empty();
            return next(queue);
        }
        
        //If load action
        $(c[0]).load(c[1], function() {
         return next(queue);
        });        
    })(queue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bannerkingbong">

</div>
<div id="bannerultra">

</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You mean when loaded ?

Comment: Yes, cuz its a gif with continuous frames

Comment: No problem `$.load` will add the response HTML to the `#element` !

Comment: how? Can you show my what do I need to change on my code please?

Comment: I took a look at your URL's they are broken no HML returned just a redirection ! Give me your urls and i will give you a working code !

Comment: OK, now we can see them:
http://smokebuddies.com.br/banner_king_bong.html
http://smokebuddies.com.br/banner_ultra420.html

Comment: I'm trying to load it on the header (after menu):

http://smokebuddies.com.br/criminalizacao-do-morro-nas-telinhas/

Its not loading the html inside div

Comment: You have CSS problem `header` position fixed is above your banner !

Comment: Sorry to hear that, i see, i will fix the CSS, now, how can i make it work as a continuous loop??